# javascriptで一瞬undefinedと表示されてしまいます

Tags: javascript, json

以下のソースをブラウザから開くと一瞬undefinedと表示されます。
何か考えられる原因はありますでしょうか？
また、以下のソースに改善すべきところがありましたら教えていただけると大変助かります。

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
      <script>
        function getJSON(){
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.open('GET', 'http://localhost/', true);
          request.responseType = 'json';
          request.onload = function () {
            var data = this.response;
            document.write('<h1>JSON TEST</h1>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                document.write('<ul>');
                document.write('<li>');
                document.write(data[i].name + '<br />');
                document.write('</li>');
                document.write('</ul>');
            }
          };
          request.send();
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        document.write(getJSON());
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: document.write(getJSON()); のgetJSON関数が戻り値を返さないから”undefined”を表示している。https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々いじってみたところ、body内のdocument.writeを消したらいけました。